# Iterate through XmlElement's Children (SelectSingleNode returning NULL)

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am trying to loop through an XML element and assign the values to member variables of an object.  Below is what I have tried.  however `SelectSingleNode()` is returning `NULL`.  data.Any is a `XmlElement` array (returned by a service).  I have tried using a `XmlNamespaceManager`, but data.Any is not a `XmlDocument` so it does not contain a `NameTable`.   What am I doing wrong?

CODE:

```
foreach (XmlElement item in data.Any)
{
    result.CorrelationID = item.SelectSingleNode("CorrelationID").InnerText;
}
```

XML:

```
<CorrelationID xmlns="http://www.host.com/folder/anotherFolder">9B36D7A7EDD26A22</CorrelationID>
<EmployerRef xmlns="http://www.host.com/folder/anotherFolder">1235/AN612</EmployerRef>
<Name xmlns="http://www.host.com/folder/anotherFolder">
<Ttl>MS</Ttl>
<Fore>NameFirst</Fore>
<Sur>NameLast</Sur>
</Name>
<PayId xmlns="http://www.host.com/folder/anotherFolder">FLDA/12</PayId>
<NINOToUse xmlns="http://www.host.com/folder/anotherFolder">SL3747A</NINOToUse>
<MessageID xmlns="http://www.host.com/folder/anotherFolder">3</MessageID>
```

Comment: The issue would seem to be the xmlns. See the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx)

Comment: Can you output/check what elements are actually in `data.Any`? If `item` in the `foreach` loop is an item in `data.Any`, and if `item` is any of the elements you show in your *XML* section, then `item` will be the `CorrelationID` element itself at some point - so the context for the XPath expression to evaluate will be that element, hence the XPath expression `CorrelationID` will not find anything as there are no further child elements of that name. (This is in addition to what @HenkHolterman has written.)

Comment: @HenkHolterman I already tried that.  please see my question :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper  data.Any is a XmlElement array that contains the XML that I posted in my question.

Comment: @Azzi: Does `item.OwnerDocument` return `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (XmlElement item in data.Any)
{
    XmlDocument doc = item.OwnerDocument;
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("af", "http://www.host.com/folder/anotherFolder");
    result.CorrelationID = item.SelectSingleNode("af::CorrelationID", nsmgr).InnerText;
}
```